# Difference between exporting inference graph and freezing graph?

Tags: tensorflow

There are two similar scripts, export_inference_graph and freeze_graph for tensorflow models. What is the difference and which one should be used in the case of training our own model? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my understanding, `export_inference_graph` is a customized script for the object detection research project.(You will have object detection model, config files, stuff like that...)
The `freeze_graph` is used to freeze general models: remove unnecessary nodes, convert vars into constants, etc.
So in your case, you will need to use `freeze_graph` for general models.